# How can I get Play Google accounts?

Tags: java, android, google-play

How can I get Play Google accounts?
If I use

```
AccountManager manager = (AccountManager) getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
        Account[] list = manager.getAccounts();
```

It gives device accounts list. Those account lists are not the same.

Comment: Please clarify your question. "Those account lists are not the same" ? What do you want ?

Comment: I need the access to current Play Google account. If I use AccountManager I just access to the ist of accounts on the phone. So hw can I get this account name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it :

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/PlusClient.html#getAccountName()

There is good documentation around that will help you with setting this up.